# Learning: Vector input in Tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, lstm

Many of the examples which I have learnt to code are of scalar input numbers. I want to try vector input. With example of https://github.com/tencia/stocks_rnn

I tried to change the code to input [x,x^2] instead of x, with following two lines of changes. But I get error.

in STOCKLSTM: 
    self._input_data = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [2, batch_size, num_steps])

In main/Epoch
    cost, state, _ = session.run([m.cost, m.final_state, eval_op],
                             {m.input_data: (x,x**2), m.targets: y, m.initial_state: state})

ERROR:
    ValueError: Cannot feed value of shape (2, 30, 10) for Tensor u'model/Placeholder:0', which has shape '(30, 10)'

Any ideas if thought direction is correct? I feel severely punished for bunking tensor classes in grad :(

Karma

Comment: I don't see anything obviously wrong on a quick glance. A couple of suggestions: is it possible that you have stale state in your Python interpreter? Try restarting Python. Another suggestion: try building a small, self-contained example of your problem; it would be easier to give helpful advice.

Comment: The 1-d works smoothly. So python stale state isn;t an issue.

Comment: Have you tried tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, batch_size, num_steps])? I was just having this issue.

Comment: cool. thanks a lot for helping.

Answer (score 0):

Here the problem is giving the batch size as a value in to the place holder. Make that 2 , none. That means it can get any amount of batch data.When using placeholders don't initiate each and everything because they are flexible structures.